# log4net configuration - GlobalContext.Property in appender not working

Tags: c#, log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

Configuring log4net in the same way I always do. I've set a global property called svr at Application_Start (ASP.NET Web Forms) and have set up the appender but it isn't working.

The appender is as follows:

```
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender_Inf" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="C:\Logs\icomply_%property{svr}_info.log" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Size" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="-1" />
  <maximumFileSize value="50GB" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%date [%thread] %-5p %message%n" />
  </layout>
  <threshold value="INFO"/>
</appender>
```

In my Global.asax.cs I have

```
private void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GlobalContext.Properties["svr"] = MyEnvironment.Server;
}
```

but the filename is icomply_(null)_info.log and the log4net trace says this (among lots of other things)

```
    log4net: Loading Appender [RollingFileAppender_Inf] type: [log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender]
    log4net: Parameter [file] specified subtype [log4net.Util.PatternString]
    log4net: Converter [literal] Option [C:\Logs\icomply_] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
    log4net: Converter [property] Option [svr] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
    log4net: Converter [literal] Option [_info.log] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
    log4net: Performing additional conversion of value from [PatternString] to [String]
    log4net: Setting Property [File] to String value [C:\Logs\icomply_(null)_info.log]
```

I can't see what I've done wrong - this is more or less what I always do, although this is probably the first time I've configured it in ASP.NET Web Forms.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had to add

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

to get this working after the

```
GlobalContext.Properties["svr"] = MyEnvironment.Server;
```

line.

Thanks NK ;-)